# How to open Word Application using SWT OLE?

Tags: plugins, swt, ole

I need to open the word application using swt ole but not in the shell rather i want open it externally i.e. as a separate application.
Please Help me.
I'm a student and not well versed in swt ole(If possible,please provide me the code).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below sample code:

```
try {
     Shell shell = new Shell(Display.getDefault());
     Composite displayArea = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
     displayArea.setLayout(new FillLayout());
     OleFrame oleFrame = new OleFrame(displayArea, SWT.NONE);
     OleClientSite clientSite = new OleClientSite(oleFrame, SWT.NONE, "Word.Document", new File(fileName));
} catch (SWTException error) {
     error.printStackTrace();
}
```